# Listeners on different mailboxes

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am looking to call a set of functions when I receive email to different mailboxes (if a mail arrives to abc@outlook.com perform function1, if a mail arrives to def@outlook.com perform function2)
I have the code below for one mailbox but I am unsure how to expand it to also listen on another mailbox without conflicting. How can I setup listeners for multiple mailboxes?
Any help appreciated. Thank you

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
   Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
   Set olApp = Outlook.Application
   Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   ' default local Inbox
   Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
'do Stuff to mailitem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another WithEvent to watch the other folder:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents Items1 As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
   Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
   Set olApp = Outlook.Application
   Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   ' default local Inbox
   Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
   Set Items1 = objNS.Folders.Item("def@outlook.com").Folders.Item("Inbox").Folders.Item("ASubFolder").Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
'do Stuff to mailitem
End Sub

Private Sub Items1_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    'do stuff.
End Sub
```